# Subset subsequent rows conditional on a difference between another value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science, cumsum

I have a dataset:

`df`

| index | ID | Date | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 76 | 1 | 2020-03-4 | -5 |
| 77 | 1 | 2020-03-4 | -6.1 |
| 78 | 1 | 2020-03-4 | -6.5 |
| 79 | 1 | 2020-03-4 | -6.4 |
| 80 | 1 | 2020-03-4 | -4 |
| 81 | 1 | 2020-03-5 | -5 |
| 82 | 1 | 2020-03-5 | -5.6 |
| 83 | 1 | 2020-03-5 | -5.5 |
| 84 | 1 | 2020-03-5 | -5.2 |
| 101 | 2 | 2020-02-14 | -3 |
| 101 | 2 | 2020-02-14 | -3.2 |
| 101 | 2 | 2020-02-14 | -5 |
| 101 | 2 | 2020-02-14 | -5.1 |
| 101 | 2 | 2020-02-14 | -5.6 |

So, multiple IDs, multiple Dates and values.

I want to return the average of the values only of those consecutive rows where the difference between the values was not greater than 1.

So, my logic behind that was to find the difference column using diff

```
df['diff'] = abs(df.groupby(['ID','Date'])['Value'].diff())
```

Then I add this Count value, where I count the consecutive rows to get something like

| Count |
| --- |
| 0 |
| 0 |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 0 |
| 0 |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 0 |
| 1 |
| 0 |
| 1 |
| 2 |

I do this by finding a True/False if less than 1 and then cumsum over that

```
df['Count'] = df.groupby(['ID','Date'])['diff'].apply(lambda x : x > 1)
df['Count'] = df.groupby([df['ID'],df['Date'],df['Count'].cumsum()])['Count'].apply(lambda x : (~x).cumsum())
```

For some reason, I think I got soooo deeply into this, that I can't figure it out, and I have a feeling it is super simple.

Ideally, I would get a new df with the largest consecutive rows where the difference is less than this.

Comment: Can you please split your question in two sections - problem: where you explain your expectations with a set of examples, and then, attempted solution: where you state what you have tried (if you think it will help other understand or answer your question).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.